# C# unit testing number precision questions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I am testing basic math functions that'll return its mean/variance/standard deviation. The problem I am facing is that I cannot get the precision of "expected value" to math what is returned by the function. For example, if the variance function returns 50.5555555555566, even if I set the expected value explicitly to 50.5555555555566, it'll say they're two different doubles and the unit test fails.

Below is the actual output from the unit test:

Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<50.5555555555556>. Actual:<50.5555555555566>.

Can anyone advise on a way around this? I am using the built-in visual studio unit testing suite. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are not comparing `Double`s to `Decimal`s.

Comment: 50.5555555555556 and 50.5555555555566 are indeed two different values!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Floating point (Single/Double)numbers need to be tested with a tolerance value. So you can say if the two numbers are within 0.0001 (tolerance) of each other, consider them equal

In NUnit, you have [comparison asserts](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=comparisonAsserts&r=2.2). e.g. the following overload of AreEqual, find the equivalent one for MSTest..

```
Assert.AreEqual( double expected, double actual, double tolerance,
                 string message );
```

**Update:** This should be [the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458.aspx) you need in MSTest. Try and see if it resolves your issue..